# Downloading a file with HtmlUnit. Download button has no (seemingly) accessible link

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am new to programming and couldn't find an answer to fit my question, and am unsure where else to turn. As stated in the title, I'm looking to download a file using HtmlUnit in Java, but the download button on the page has no href or onclick I can access. Button follows:

```html
<button class="btn btn-download btn-primary pull-right" id="eta_download" style="display: block;">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
</button>
```

clicking this button causes a normal browser to do some processing and loading for a short amount of time, then open a tab that triggers the download of a gzip file containing a tiff satellite image. I am doing this in a Swing app.

[The site I need to download gzipped tiff from](https://eeflux-level1.appspot.com/)

Can anyone help me get this to work?

My code follows:

```
// Call from whithin new Thread. Get the download 
private void getDownload(String latitude, String longitude, String start, String end) throws Exception
{
    // Create the browser
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    // Report to user. Loading page...
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            reportLabel.setText("Loading EEFLUX...");
        }
    });

    // Load page
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://eeflux-level1.appspot.com/");

    // Report to user change in state
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            reportLabel.setText("Filling in values");
        }
    });

    // Get Latitude, Lomgitude and Date Fields
    HtmlInput latitudeField = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("latitude");
    HtmlInput longitudeField = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("longitude");
    HtmlInput date_start_Field = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("date_start");
    HtmlInput date_end_Field = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("date_end");

    // Set the values of fields to that passed into method
    latitudeField.setAttribute("value", latitude);
    longitudeField.setAttribute("value", longitude);
    date_start_Field.setAttribute("value", start);
    date_end_Field.setAttribute("value", end);

    // Get the Search "Button" then click
    HtmlAnchor search = (HtmlAnchor) page.getHtmlElementById("searchForImages");
    page = search.click();

    // wait for Javascripts jobs to finish
    JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
    for (int i = 0; manager.getJobCount() > 7; i++)
    {
        final int j = i;
        // Report to user change in state
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                reportLabel.setText("Loading after Search: " + j);
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    // Get the list of regions Satellites captured and click to open dropdown
    HtmlDivision image_dropdown = (HtmlDivision) page.getElementById("image_dropdown");
    image_dropdown.click();

    // Get the list of regions
    HtmlUnorderedList region_list = (HtmlUnorderedList) image_dropdown.getLastElementChild();      

    // get iterator for list
    Iterator<DomElement> web_list = region_list.getChildElements().iterator();


    // Report to user change in state
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            reportLabel.setText("Accessing region list");
        }
    });

    // for each Element, download Actual ET image (and later Grass Reference)
    while(web_list.hasNext())
    {

        DomElement region = web_list.next();

        System.out.println(region.getTextContent());

        HtmlPage page2 = region.click();

        // wait for Javascripts jobs to finish
        manager = page2.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
        for (int i = 0; manager.getJobCount() > 2; i++)
        {
            final int j = i;
            // Report to user
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    reportLabel.setText("Loading Image Type page: " + j);
                }
            });
            System.out.println(manager.getJobCount());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        // Get the Actual ET download Button
        HtmlButton ETButton = page2.getHtmlElementById("eta_download");

        // Get the Download Page????
        HtmlPage page3 = ETButton.click();
        UnexpectedPage download_ET = new UnexpectedPage(page3.getWebResponse(), page3.getEnclosingWindow());

        // Get the Stream
        GZIPInputStream in_ET = (GZIPInputStream) download_ET.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();

        // Try writing the stream (to standard out for now)
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            int len;
            while((len = in_ET.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                System.out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the stream
            in_ET.close();
        }
        // just do one till this works
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good start :) 
I looked at the request being sent when clicking the button :

[image: Post request when clicking the button]

As you can see there are several parameters being sent (latitude, longitude, date_end, image_id). In the response, you have the download URL.
This request is generated with some Javascript code, probably this :

```
function downloadImage(divName,urlProduct){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(divName).on('click', function(){
        onlyshowLoading();
        $.ajax({
            url: urlProduct,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "lat": $('#latitude').val(),
                "lng": $('#longitude').val(),
                "date_info": $('#date_start').val() + ' to ' + $('#date_end').val(),
                'image_id': $("#dropdown:first-child").text().split(" / ")[1],
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            error: function(){
                AjaxOnError();
            },              
            success: function(data){
                AjaxOnSuccess();
                if (typeof ETa_adjusted  == "undefined" || ETa_adjusted  == null){
                    $("#ETrF_adjusted").hide();
                    $("#EToF_adjusted").hide(); 
                    $("#ETa_adjusted").hide();
                    $("#etrF_adj_download").hide();
                    $("#etoF_adj_download").hide();
                    $("#eta_adj_download").hide();
                } else{
                    $("#ETrF_adjusted").show();
                    $("#EToF_adjusted").show(); 
                    $("#ETa_adjusted").show();
                    $("#etrF_adj_download").show();
                    $("#etoF_adj_download").show();
                    $("#eta_adj_download").show();

                }
                var key = Object.keys(data);
                typeName = data[key]
                window.open(typeName.url, '_blank');                     
            }
        });        
    });
})
```

}

So it's possible that HtmlUnit is unable to execute this code, because of Jquery or whatever. 
You could create your own WebRequest object, and reproduce the Javascript logic, then you will get the download URL.

It's an interesting subject, if you want to know more I'm in the middle of writing an ebook about web scraping with Java : [Java Web Scraping Handbook](https://javawebscrapinghandbook.com)